# Vector subspace clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We need to check if the following sets are vector subspaces:

$$ S_1=\{(0,0),(1,2),(2,1)  \};V=(\Bbb Z_3)^2 \\
 S_2=\{P\mid\exists x \in \Bbb R :P_{(x)}=0  \};V=\Bbb R_n [x]$$

For $S_1$ I just add: $u+v=(1,2)+(2,1)=(3,3)=(1,1) \notin S_1$ so this is not a vector subspace.

For $S_2$, P is a polynomial. I don't understand this notation: $V=\Bbb R_n [x]$ and as far as I understand, the set means that there are some $x$ that gives the zero solution to the polynomial but I have no idea how to apply it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Erm. $(3,3)=(0,0)\not=(1,1)$ unless I misunderstood.

Comment: And $\Bbb R_n[x]$ is the space of all polynomials of degree $\le n$.

Comment: And $S_2$ is the set of all polynomial that have a real root.

Comment: @xavierm02 You mean: $(3,3)=(0,0) \ mod3 $ ? Well, then it is a subspace. Can you explain how did you know that about $S_2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(1)$, note that we are working with $($ the integers under addition modulo $3)^2$. So $$u+v=(1,2)+(2,1)=(3,3)=(0,0) \in S_1$$

For the second, $\Bbb R_n[x]$ is the space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$. In effect, $S_2$ consists of all polynomials with at least one real root.

Hint for $(2)$. We have $$P_1 = (x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 \in S_2,\quad P_2 = 1-x \in S_2$$
But $$P_1 + P_2 = x^2 + x + 2 \notin S_2, \;\text{since} \;\not\exists x \in \mathbb R \;\text{such that }\; x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$$

Comment: How do you know that about S_2 ?

Comment: I'm not clear what it is you're asking. We have the set of polynomials for which there is a real number x satisfying $P(x) = 0$. By definition of a root, then, it is the set of polynomials that have a real root, since $\exists x\in \mathbb R$, where $P$ evaluated at $x$ is zero. And the notation $\mathbb R_n[x]$ is simply how we denote the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

Comment: So the definition of a root is where a polynomial (function) equal zero ? I didn't know that definition.

Comment: Perhaps in order to be even clearer it should be remarked that $\;S_2\;$ is the set of all polynomials *of degree less than* $\;n\;$ (or up to $\;n\;$ , depends on one's definition) which have at least one real root.

Comment: Yes, GinKin, a root of a polynomial is precisely where that function equals zero.